Как настроить binding внутри собственных UserControl?
Пробую создать свой кастомный контрол. Но столкнулся с тем, что в нём не работает Binding к заданному мною свойству.
У класса контрола есть свойство Text (это же не техническое имя? Его можно использовать?)
Внутри контрола к нему привязан текст в TextBox
Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
Сам класс реализует интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged
Вот его реализация (она нормальная? Такую можно использовать?):
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected void SetOptions<T>(string property, ref T variable, T value)
    {
        variable = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

Покопавшись понял, что для того, что бы была возможность выполнять Binding, ужно делать через DependencyProperty (в этом случае нужен вообще INotifyPropertyChanged ?)
Сделал следующее :
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty;
    
    static ConsoleTextBox()
    {
        TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Text),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ConsoleTextBox));
    }

В самом свойстве прописал вот так вот :
    public string? Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            //SetOptions(nameof(Text), ref _text, value);//Так до этого вызывал INotifyPropertyChanged
        } 
    }

Цепляться к нему пытаюсь вот так :
 <local:ConsoleTextBox Text="{Binding Input, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
Но почему-то ничего не происходит и текст не меняется, при изменении значений Input. Хотя тут же добавил обычный TextBlock и точно так же сделал Binding, и в нём всё работает.
Я что-то явно делаю не так, но не могу понять, что именно.
Тестовый проект с моими попытками реализации : https://github.com/spasskiy/ConsoleTextBoxTestProject
Из другого элемента пробую биндиться к моему
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=consoleTextBox, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
Биндинг прекрасно работает с обеих сторон и в обе стороны. А из моего контрола почему-то нет.

Какая задача вашего контрола? Просто вывести красиво текст, или это отдельная страница проекта? Если чисто текст, то у вас там не должно вообще быть чего либо связанного с данными, у вас там должна быть только логика UI и ничего более. Другими словами, я вот вижу у вас текстовое поле и кнопку, вот это у вас должно привязываться снаружи (<control Text = "{Binding Text}" Command = "{Binding ClickCommand}"/>) и уже тот, кто руководит контролом выводит там диалоговые окна и все, что надо. Сейчас у вас куча лишнего там, не его ответственность скажем так...

Также вы делаете ряд странностей по типу if (_scrollBar.IsVisible) clearButton.Margin = new Thickness(0, 4, 22, 0);  - это тоже не часть кода, а часть XAML, с его триггерами и прочим. Что касается привязок, то я не вижу там источника данных., вот в конце вопроса вы показали привязку с ElementName - вот такая у вас должна быть внутри контрола, где именем будет сам контрол... То есть <UserControl x:Name="uc"><TextBox Text = "{Binding Text, ElementName = uc}"/>. Ну и да, INPC в контроле тоже лишний, ибо повторю, он не должен руководить данными.

@EvgeniyZ Контрол это TextBox с кнопкой в правом верхнем углу. Если скролбара у TextBox нету, то кнопка липнет к краю. Если скрол бар появился, смещается левее, что бы его не закрывать. Контрол встраивается в форму. Нужно пробросить биндинг, что бы при изменении значения свойства у объекта во VieModel, оно отображалось в этом контроле в TextBox. Свойство текстовое.

@EvgeniyZ тут основной вопрос не столько по данному контролу а о том, как вообще правильно делать свойства в контролах, к которым можно биндиться извне?

Повторю, вы не должны вообще что либо знать про данные) Как привязываться, я вам сказал выше, просто задайте имя контролу в XAML и укажите его в привязке. Все, дальше оперируйте только DependencyProperty и тем, что есть в самом контроле. Например, если хотите узнать что свойство обновилось, то задайте DependencyProperty нужный Callback, который будет вызываться при изменениях. Ваш контрол должен быть максимально абстрагированным и отделенным от всего приложения, следуйте этому правилу.

Можете посмотреть стандартный TextBox, как он реализован. Вот код, а вот XAML. Обратите внимание на TextProperty (там вызов калбека при изменении), а также обратите внимание на то как в XAML привязывается TemplateButtonCommand , вот RelativeSource= можно заменить на то, как я сказал выше (ElementName=uc).

@EvgeniyZ не совсем понимаю "не должны вообще что либо знать про данные". Он просто должен их отображать. Как он будет делать это, ничего не зная про данные?
Сейчас уткнулся с тем, что у обычного TextBox вот такая привязка Text="{Binding Input работает, а в моём нет. Но прям тут же делаю привязку в моём контроле к Text="{Binding ElementName=TB, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" и всё, мой контрол начинает через TextBox транслировать привязку в обе стороны. Почему так?

Так же срабатывает вот такая привязка {Binding Path=Input, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}
Пробовал DataContext на всякий случай ему прописать от окна, не помогает. Не понимаю, почему одна привязка, к XAML объектам, срабатывает, а другая, к данным, нет?

В общем кажется я понял, в чём дело. Кастомный контрол берёт DataContext от самого себя, а не от того элемента в котором он размещён. Поэтому привязка ElementName срабатывает, а относительные привязки нет. Добился того эффекта, который хотел через вот такую привязку Binding ElementName=ThisWindow, Path=DataContext.Item - предварительно задав окну имя. Кажется это очень костыльное решение. Что бы сделать привязку, которая будет нормально работать, нужно разбираться с DependencyProperty ? В нём что-то не так?

@EvgeniyZ Всё. Кажется разобрался. Это я идиот. У моего кастомного контрола сам же и задал DataContext = this; Из-за этого такие проблемы и начались. Большое спасибо. Ваши советы и ссылка на оригинальный TextBox очень помогли.
